# How do you ignore white spaces and punctuation?

Tags: java, palindrome

How do you make this return the palindrome boolean value ignoring spaces and punctuation?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringUtil
{
    public static boolean Palindrome(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
            return true;

        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
            return Palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type in a string to check if its a palindrome or not");
        String p = check.nextLine();
        if(Palindrome(p))
            System.out.println(p + " is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(p+ " is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to try to add code to make this code ignore spaces and punctuation then if it doesn't work ask a specific question.  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I would pass in something that is the result of removing all punctuation and white space.

Comment: Just a few recommendation as seems you are beginner on Java: 1. Learn how to indent your code.  2. Stick to Java naming conventions.  For example, your method name should start with lowercase character: i.e. should be `palindrome(...)` instead of `Palindrome(...)` (or even better, `isPalindrome(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `String.replaceAll`, you define what you want to replace, in this case, whitespaces and punctuation, so we will use `\\W` as what we want to find and replace it with nothing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringUtil{

public static boolean Palindrome(String s)
{

    if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
        return true;

    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return Palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

    return false;

}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("type in a string to check if its a palindrome or not");
    String p = check.nextLine();

    //We replace all of the whitespace and punctuation 
    p = p.replaceAll("\\W", "");

    if(Palindrome(p))
        System.out.println(p + " is a palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println(p+ " is not a palindrome");
}

}
```

Sample Output

```
type in a string to check if its a palindrome or not
r';:.,?!ace    car
racecar is a palindrome
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand it!

Comment: Anytime, if you could just accept this as the answer so this question can be closed.